# if condition applied on the keys of a dictionnary

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am trying to run the following code:

```
a={'1':2,'3':4}
b=1

for k,v in a.iteritems():
     if k==b:
         print k,v
```

I expected to obtain the result:

1 2

But nothing happened. Could you explain me why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is python correct?

Comment: `1 != '1'` .... `1 == int('1')`, `str(1) == '1'`,  `1 == 1`, and `'1' == '1'`

Comment: Ok next time don't forget to add the language to the tags to get replies from people that use python.

Answer (score 2):

The key is a string, you should write

```
if k=='1':
```

If you want to use your version you should declare the dictionary as `a={1:2,3:4}`

Comment: Thank you. In fact, i use it in a more complicated code and I would like to write something like ' if k==b:...'where b is a varibale. This procedure will be impossible?

Comment: No, it is possibile but you have to look at what types you are using. Also note that that you can access a value just by specifing `a[b]` and in order to check the existance of a key you can write `b in a`.